# how to convert unknown format according to my system culture info?

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime, invalidation

How do I convert an anonymous date format to my own system culture info?

I am using a jquery calendar .datepicker(), but when I'm trying to get the value of that text box in the c# datetime variable, it shows invalid date time string. I have tried datetime.tryparse ,datetime.parse,convert.todatetime() and many others.

Now I am trying to get the date in jquery like `var a = date.now();`

But I am getting the following error: `date.prototype //invalid date`

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: What value is being returned?

Comment: If it's unknown, how will you test for correctness?

Comment: i am getting Fri Oct 25 21:03:28 UTC+0530 2013 in var a but,getting the error in date.prototype //invalid date

Comment: var a=date.now(); i am getting value in 'a' is "Fri Oct 25 21:03:28 UTC+0530 2013" but i am also getting error in prototype= invalid date and when i am trying to using this var a to set the date in another calendar, i can't use it as a date because its not a valid date (its showing prototype=invalid date)

Comment: the date is invalid according to my system culture info.

Comment: Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: any example will be very helpful?

Comment: You'll have to figure iut the exact format but something like: `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MM DD HH:mm:ss z YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments (" i am also getting error in prototype= invalid date and when i am trying to using this var a to set the date in another calendar"), I think you're trying to set calendars within jquery, possibly within an asp.net page.

If this is the case, you can set the date format when you create the datepicker :

```
$( ".calendar" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-yyyy" }); // 10-25-2013
```

Format it as you need. For a list of date formatting options, see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate.

If this doesn't help, it would be useful to know :
* what is emitting the date
* what is consuming the date (jquery/ C#)
* the actual code that is generating errors, if any.

After reading your responses, I think you should try specifying the format of your datepicker explicitly.

Comment: i am getting `Fri Oct 25 21:03:28 UTC+0530 2013` in var a but,getting the error in date.prototype //invalid date

Comment: and in c# when i am trying to use store the textbox value in `datetime` it shows `invalid datetime string`

Comment: @RKSharmaSharma I think you should try specifying the format of your datepicker explicitly.